# Python - How to read a file that was selected from Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is for my assignment.
I was given a template like this... def_choosefile() :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

root_window = tkinter.Tk()
root_window.withdraw()

return filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

So if i get this correct, it'll prompt a dialog window, asking to select a file. And when a file is selected, the program is supposed to tell what files did it pick. Using these:

```
selected_file = choose_file()
print ("Selected file: {}".format (selected_file))
```

after that, how do i make the program read the files normally? Normally i would use:

```
infile = open('text')
infile.readline()
```

Comment: I suppose the return statement should be inside the choose_file function?

Comment: err... i forgot to mention that the first one is def choose_file() function

Comment: Have you tried what you normally use? What happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

root_window = tkinter.Tk()
root_window.withdraw()

def choose_file():
    return filedialog.askopenfilename()

selected_file = choose_file()

with open (selected_file,'r') as readfile:
     lines = readfile.read().splitlines()

for line in lines[0:2]:
    print (line)
```

Comment: i have to read multiple lines, and after that, split em and assign each words to a variable for drawing

Comment: If you iterate readfile with a for loop, you get all the lines one by one. You can split or assign them however you want.

Comment: well, i want the first two line to have their own if-conditionals. How do i do that?

Comment: Separated the first 2 lines. Just add an if statement. Changed my code above.

Comment: nevermind that, i already used a variable called 'loop_count' that goes up everytime a loop is done, and i have an if statement for the first line.

Comment: now the question is                                                                                                  with open (selected_file,'r') as readfile:
    for line in readfile:                                                                                               the 'line' part... Can it be changed into word? Or is it just a "counter" just like the i in "for i in range (x)"??